# react-native-webview crashes on Android when I select file upload

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-webview

I'm trying to use react-native-webview to load the website which can take picture or upload photo from the device. 
My settings are as below and I can take a picture directly but it is not clear so I'm trying to upload photo from the device but the app crashes whenever I select upload files. It shows options (camera, file) when I click on upload file option but as soon as I try to go back or take a picture, the app crashes. Is there a way to solve this?

```
mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={false}
startInLoadingState={true}
allowsInlineMediaPlayback={true}
allowFileAccess={true}
allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs={true}
useWebKit
javaScriptEnabled
source={{ uri: 'uri' }}
originWhitelist={['*']}
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding this permission to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```